# NuxtJS проблема с передачей параметра из урл в асинхронный запрос

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

В документации к Nuxt.js в разделе "Асинхронные данные" есть пример получения данных от api с помощью axios:

```js
export default { 
 async data ({ params }) {
  let { data } = await axios.get(`https://my-api/posts/${params.id}`)
  return { title: data.title }
 }
}
```

Но вот незадача, params.id - который хранит в себе id статьи, полученный из url, отдает undefined.
При этом во всех гайдах и документациях у всех все работает!
Спустя несколько часов е**ли и проклятий в сторону современного фронтенда мною был найден на гитхабе чейто репозиторий с примером сайта на Nuxt (чтото про собачек),
поглядел я как там чел получает этот параметр и увидел +params.id, добавил плюсик к переменной и вуаля!
В итоге для меня так и осталось загадкой назначение этого плюсика, почему без него ничего не работает.

Догадка №1 : Я что-то делаю не так.

Догадка №2 : Обновили фреймворк и забыли исправить докумментацию (маловероятно).

Блог который я пытаюсь сделать: 
http://f4rr3ll.cc.ua/articles/2/

Код блога с этими 'плюсиками' (20 строка):
https://github.com/f4rr3ll1990/f4rr3ll_nuxt_blog/blob/master/pages/article/_id.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не просто асинхронные данные, а вычисляемое свойство + асинхронность.

> Вычисляемые свойства не могут содержать в себе асинхронной логики вычисления значения

Подробнее об этом можно почитать [тут](https://medium.com/@modex13/vue-js-2-computed-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-6649a2169b67)

Comment: ну я код взял тупо из документации к Nuxt, полагаю что так делать можно, вопрос в другом, оно не особо корректно работает ((

Comment: @f4rr3ll ваш случай может не соответствовать тому что приведен в офф. документации. Плюс уже и ссылки в вопросе не открываются

Comment: Я уже разобрался, если интересно то тут все описал))
http://f4rr3ll.cc.ua/articles/5a92bd44700f140800007497/

Comment: @f4rr3ll вы можете ответить на свой вопрос и отметить его как решение. Здесь это поощряется.